# Is there any way to store functions in variables and create lists of variable-housed functions?

Tags: python, list, function

Am new to Python - have done some scripting in PHP, javascript, but am not a programmer (though am a tech writer with experience documenting APIs etc, so pretty extensive 'passive' programming know how).:

1. Was following steps here: https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/A_Beginner's_Python_Tutorial/Functions. Specifically see the link re: simple calculator program
2. Wanted to figure out if I could make the program less redundant by storing all components for different calculations in list form, then have a very simple, generic means of processing any calculation request, by using the user's menu choice as an index into the list. I'm assuming it's good form to structure things in this way, but don't know! The original tutorial is obviously much more readable, but would mean the same error checking would need to be done repeatedly for each little "if" block...

In any case though, I couldn't figure out how to store the actual calculations as elements within a list. Is that possible? Here's as far as I got... where I managed to encapsulate, and call on, some of the specifics within lists, but had to still do a series of "if" statements for each individual calculation.

(Sorry if these questions are basic.. I did a bunch of searching without finding definitive documentation re: here's everything you can and Cannot capture in list form) So - my variation of the linked-to code:

```
#simple calculator program
# Prompts for possible calculations

add = ["Add this: ", "to this: ", "+"]
subtract = ["Subtract this: ", "from this: ", "-"]
multiply = ["Multiply this: ", "by this: ", "*"]
divide = ["Divide this: ", "by this: ", "/"]

# List of possible calculations
calcPrompts = [add, subtract, multiply, divide]

def promptEntries(Arg):
    try:
        op1 = int(input(Arg[0]))
        op2 = int(input(Arg[1]))
        operator = (Arg[2])
        return op1, op2, operator
    except:
        print("Invalid entry. Please try again.")
choice = 0

#This variable tells the loop whether it should loop or not.
# 1 means loop. Anything else means don't loop.

loop = 1

while loop == 1:
    #Display the available options
    print ("\n\nCalculator options are:")
    print (" ")
    print ("1) Addition")
    print ("2) Subtraction")
    print ("3) Multiplication")
    print ("4) Division")
    print ("5) Quit calculator.py")
    print (" ")

    try:
        choice = int(input("Choose your option: "))
        choice = choice - 1
        op1, op2, operator = promptEntries(calcPrompts[choice])
        print(op1, operator, op2, "=", end=" ")
        if choice == 0:
            print(op1 + op2)
        elif choice == 1:
            print(op1 - op2)
        elif choice == 2:
            print(op1 * op2)
        elif choice == 3:
            if op2 != 0:
                print(op1 / op2)
            else:
                print("Division by zero is invalid, please try again.")
        elif choice == 4:
            loop = 0
            print ("Thank you for using calculator.py")
    except:
        print("invalid entry, please try again.")
```

Answer (score 2):

In your case, you can use the operators as functions, provided by the `operator` standard library module.

As you can see, you can assign such functions to a variable, e.g. inserting all of them in a list

```
import operator as op
f = [op.add,
     op.sub,
     op.mul,
     op.div,
     op.pow,
     op.mod]
```

then the loop can become

```
while True:
    #Display the available options
    print ("\n\nCalculator options are:")
    for i, fun in enumerate(f):
        print("{}) {}".format(i+1, fun.__name__))
    print ("{}) Quit calculator.py".format(len(f)))

    choice = int(input("Choose your option: ")) - 1
    if choice == len(f):
        print("Thank you for using calculator.py")
        break
    op1 = int(input("enter operand1: "))
    op2 = int(input("enter operand2: "))

    try:
        result = f[choice](op1, op2)
    except IndexError:
        print("invalid entry, please try again.")
    except ZeroDivisionError:
        print("Division by zero is invalid, please try again.")

    print('{} {} {} = {}'.format(op1, f[choice].__name__, op2, result))
```

Note: the example works for dyadic functions only. Further work is needed in case you want to offer a mix of functions with a different number of arguments.

Comment: Thanks for the code, Pynchia. Very much appreciate the initial info re: importing Operator .. module(?)... and ability to create list as a result. Beyond that... enough uncommented code with which I'm not yet familiar. Will attempt to decipher them and figure out, among other things, where the menu disappeared to! :-) Among other things, the aggregated syntax is currently foreign to me: for i, fun in enumerate(f):
        print("{}) {}".format(i+1, fun.__name__))... But I appreciate the posting - food for thought! :-)... much to learn

Comment: You are welcome. Please be kind and accept an answer and/or upvote the ones you got

Comment: Hi Pynchia, let me see first if I can make one, or a combination of both answers work in my code exercise, in which case I will be happy to accept answer/upvote. (May not have time to get to it for a couple days.) Have a good night.

Comment: Worked with your code - a couple minor errors I found + comments: "div" caused error - there is a "truediv" in operator module, so used that instead. Also changed format(len(f))) above to format(len(f)+1)), otherwise menu item number is duplicated. Next challenge is to make the interface more "user friendly". Your code is efficient (and appreciated!) - I learned stuff beyond the scope of my original question by playing with it. Next step though, is to make prompts and results "user friendly", since your code grabs abbreviated stuff from op module

Comment: Continued from above - So I'll experiment with that... For instance, here's what code produces currently Calculator options are:
1) add
2) sub
3) mul
4) truediv
5) Quit calculator.py
Choose your option: 1
enter operand1: 2
enter operand2: 2
2 add 2 = 4

Comment: yes, the code uses the name of the function (`add` in that case)

Comment: yep, thanks, Pynchia - I understood that :-) That's why the next step for me is to find a simple elegant way of associating friendly english language prompts and result statements with each function... need to teach myself next I'm guessing, re: lists of lists and-or how to link an item in one list to a 'partner' item in another...

Answer (score 1):

Yes, in python functions are first class objects and you can use them any way that you would use any other object. For example you can have two variables reference the same object:

```
def myFunction():
    pass

newVariable = myFunction
print(newVariable is myFunction)
```

or reference functions from a list or dictionary:

```
myList = [myFunction, 1, 2, 3]
print(myList[0] is myFunction)
myDict = {0:myFunction, 1:1}
print(myDict[0] is myFunction)
```

The above is true for both python's built in functions, functions in the standard library and functions you write. For example:

```
from operator import add

def countZeros(a):
    return sum(item == 0 for item in a)

listOfFunctions = [sum, add, countZeros]
```

Comment: Thanks, Bi Rico. Will work with what you've provided and see if I can come up with new and improved code bit.